# how to make variables as variables while storing in javascript

Tags: javascript

My problem is I am having an url as

```
var slctdOffsets;
var tat_Name;
var ref;

"?request=execRltdSrv&parentSrvObjRef=" + parentSrvObjRefW1 + "&lat=-1&long=-1&
slctdOffsets=" + slctdOffsets + "&srvRef=IAWMblztnExpert-ListSIBCs-ListIICsInSIBC_MB&
tatRef=" + tat_Name + "&suppressID=1"
```

This url has been initialized to a variable

```
var url = "?request=execRltdSrv&parentSrvObjRef=" + parentSrvObjRefW1 + "&lat=-1&long=-1&
slctdOffsets=" + slctdOffsets + "&srvRef=IAWMblztnExpert-ListSIBCs-ListIICsInSIBC_MB&
tatRef=" + tat_Name + "&suppressID=1";

function populateIICs(slctdOffsets, tat_Name) {
        var bindId = "#wrapper3";
        console.log(parentSrvObjRefW1);
        var url = slider3URL;
        console.log(url);
        getJSONDATA(url, function(res) {
            parentSrvObjRefW2 = res.response.output.srvObjRef;
            $('#add2').removeClass('ui-disabled');

            addIICToSlider_success(res, bindId, iic_icon)
        }, function(res) {
            addItemToSlider_error(res, bindId)
        });

    }
```

This variable has been used in some function where the values for parentSrvObjRefW1 ,slctdOffsets  and tat_Name are given. but the problem is the variables as getting value as undefined and I am not able to run the url, can someone help me to resolve this problem please. Thanks

Comment: Obviously the parameters haven't been supplied properly. You need to show more code so we can tell why this is happening.

Comment: As @Barmar said, we need more code please

Comment: do you init said variable before the function runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the variable to be set with a function upon calling it, you need to have a function for each variable individually:

```
var url = "?request=execRltdSrv&parentSrvObjRef=" + parentSrvObjRefW1() + "&lat=-1&long=-1&
slctdOffsets=" + slctdOffsets() + "&srvRef=IAWMblztnExpert-ListSIBCs-ListIICsInSIBC_MB&
tatRef=" + tat_Name() + "&suppressID=1";
```

and then the function:

```
function parentSrvObjRefW1() {
    var result = '';
    // do your stuff
    return result;
}

function slctdOffsets() {
    var result = '';
    // do your stuff
    return result;
}

function tat_Name() {
    var result = '';
    // do your stuff
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what i need is the variable should be as variable and calling that function then the viarable should be get initialized with that value

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not the url var issue, the logic to generate `parentSrvObjRefW1` or `tat_Name` is incorrect. This is making those variables `undefined`. 
Or you are not initialising the parameter.

Comment: on calling the function i need to pass those values to variables in that url how can i do that?